# Django on apache2/mod_wsgi and collectstatic

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-staticfiles

I'm configuring Django on Apache under Ubuntu 11.04. My media files is not available.

httpd.conf

```
Alias /robots.txt /home/i159/workspace/prod-shivablog/shivablog/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /home/i159/workspace/prod-shivablog/shivalog/favicon.ico

AliasMatch ^/([^/]*\.css) /home/i159/workspace/prod-     shivablog/shivablog/site_media/static/css/$1

Alias /media/ /home/i159/workspace/prod-shivablog/shivablog/site_media/static/
Alias /static/ /home/i159/workspace/prod-shivablog/shivablog/site_media/static/

<Directory /home/i159/workspace/prod-shivablog/shivablog/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /home/i159/workspace/prod-shivablog/shivablog/media>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/i159/workspace/prod-shivablog/shivablog/deploy/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess local-shivablog.com python-path=/home/i159/workspace/prod-    shivablog/shivablog/:/home/i159/.envs/shivablog/python2.7/site-packages

<Directory /home/i159/workspace/prod-shivablog/shivablog>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

urls

```
# Static files url.
(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                                   {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
(r'^site_media/static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                                {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```

wsgi

```
import os, sys

sys.path.insert(0,  os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), os.pardir,  os.pardir)))
sys.path.insert(0,  os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), os.pardir)))

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "shivablog.settings"
application = WSGIHandler()
```

settings

```
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = "/site_media/static/"
```

How to make my media files available? What the configurations are correct? After `collectstatic` all the static and media files collects to `site_media/static`. Should I get my media files from this directory (`site_media/static`)?

Comment: Your Apache config looks roughly correct. What error are you getting? Have you checked your Apache logs?

Comment: I have an error 403 - have not this url on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have an entry in your urls.py file for media or static files. If you do at least wrap them in a cause which only does this in debug mode = True.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/

```
(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                                   {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
(r'^site_media/static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                                {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```

Also your .htaccess file has the following lines which point to the same folder, I think they should be different as your static files are not in your media folder.

```
Alias /media/ /home/i159/workspace/prod-shivablog/shivablog/site_media/static/
Alias /static/ /home/i159/workspace/prod-shivablog/shivablog/site_media/static/
```